# What is the reason for using (if false !== ...)

Tags: php

The question says it all! I have noticed this statement a lot:

```
if (false !== some_expression)
```

Instead of

```
if(some_expression !== false)
```

Is there a reason to use the first statement style over the second?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could say, that it is the other way;) That some people use `some_expression !== false` instead of `false !== some_expression`. Matter of taste, a bit. And seek of consistency.

So often people write `'foo' == $bar` instead of `$bar == 'foo'` as kind of protection from misspelling `$bar = 'foo'` what would be difficult to spot. `'foo' = $bar` would cause syntax error. So if you write equality checks that way, then you want to code other conditions in similar way.

Additionally, that can be a bit more readable if you have more complex expression on one side, because at least from start you know with what are you comparing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I knew there was a reason...its not just a matter of "taste"...

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly the same thing.

A comparison have no order.

Look at this **JS example**, the result is the same with **php** and **other languages**

**Example**

```js
var some_expression = ((2>0) && (9!=9)); // Expression = false

var result1 = some_expression !== false; 
var result2 = false !== some_expression;
var result3 = result1 === result2;

console.log("Result 1 : "+result1);
console.log("Result 2 : "+result2);
console.log("Result 3 : "+result3);
```

Comment: Oh yes, but the result it's the same with JS. More understandable with example